# Strange Result : sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t) in Kernel?

Tags: cuda, sizeof

I'am working in win8.1 64bit CUDA7.5 GTX960 compute_52,sm_52.

I tried to get the size of CUDA Object as below.

```
printf("sizeof(int*)=%d sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t)=%d sizeof(cudaSurfaceObject_t)=%d sizeof(cudaArray_t)=%d\n", sizeof(int*), sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t), sizeof(cudaSurfaceObject_t), sizeof(cudaArray_t));
```

I've got the below.

1) in Host Code

```
sizeof(int*)=8 sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t)=8 sizeof(cudaSurfaceObject_t)=8 sizeof(cudaArray_t)=8
```

2) in Kernel Code

```
sizeof(int*)=8 sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t)=0 sizeof(cudaSurfaceObject_t)=8 sizeof(cudaArray_t)=0
```

My Question :
Why `sizeof(cudaTextureObject_t)=0` and `sizeof(cudaArray_t)=0` ?

Comment: From a construction point of view, for example for `cudaTextureObject_t`,  the answer is contained in `texture_types.h` and `host_defines.h`.  I'm assuming your question is "why was it designed this way?", not "how is it that the item is 8 bytes on the host and 0 bytes on the device?"

Comment: OK, then..I will think cudaTextureObject_t as virtual data type for compiler, not real data type such as int, long ...

Comment: What real data type is the converted data type of cudaTextureObject_t and cudaArray_t?

Comment: __global__ void my_kernel(cudaTextureObject_t tex) {  __shared__ cudaTextureObject_t stex; stex = tex; } <======= can't assign, impossible?

Comment: sizeof 0 is invalid in C++. sizeof 0 is possible in C, but undefined.